# Create a collection of js objects by deserialising a collection of json objects in node.js

Tags: javascript, java, json, node.js, jackson

I have an prototype class:

```
function temp(){
    this.a=77;
}

temp.prototype.getValue = function(){
    console.log(this.a);
}
```

and an array of json objects:

```
var x=[{a:21},{a:22},{a:23}];
```

Is there any way to instantiate an array of class `temp` directly using the array of json objects in a similar way to what generics helps us to achieve in Java using Jackson TypeReference.

```
var y= new Array(new temp());
//something similar to what Object.assign achieves for a single object
```

Thus can it be extended to other collection of objects like `Map<obj1,obj2>`,etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in way to do that in Javascript.  With a few assumptions about your data or about a constructor, you could fairly simply create your own function to create such an array:

```
// pass the constructor for the object you want to create
// pass an array of data objects where each property/value will be copied
// to the newly constructed object
// returns an array of constructed objects with properties initialized
function createArrayOfObjects(constructorFn, arrayOfData) {
    return arrayOfData.map(function(data) {
        let obj = new constructorFn();
        Object.keys(data).forEach(function(prop) {
           obj[prop] = data[prop];
        });
        return obj;
    });
}
```

Or, you can create a constructor that takes an object of data and then initializes itself from that object:

```
// pass the constructor for the object you want to create
// pass an array of data objects that will each be passed to the constructor
// returns an array of constructed objects 
function createArrayOfObjects(constructorFn, arrayOfData) {
    return arrayOfData.map(function(data) {
        return new constructorFn(data);
    });
}

// constructor that initializes itself from an object of data passed in
function Temp(data) {
    if (data && data.a) {
        this.a = data.a;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could directly fill an array with the instances of `Temp` with [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).

```js
function Temp(){
    this.a=77;
}

Temp.prototype.getValue = function(){
    console.log(this.a);
}

var array = Array.from({ length: 5 }, _ => new Temp);

array[0].a = 42;
console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using NPM, I strongly recommend `linq-collections` package for this kind of things.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/linq-collections